# Confused on how to upload variables from swift to php files for mysql use

Tags: php, swift, xcode

I have an app in xcode where I will be taking notes and uploading them to a server on the web. I have the following code in xcode to POST. I'm getting an error

```
 The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
```

Here are my parameters to upload to php

```
 let parameters: [String: Any] = ["title": title, "post": post]
```

Here is my create Post code

```
  func createPost(parameters: [String: Any]) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "\(prefixUrl)/post.php") else {
            print("Did not find url")
            return
        }
        
        let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = data
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
    
      URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request ) { (data, res, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("error", error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
                return
            }
            do {
                if let data = data {
                    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode([postDataBase].self, from: data)
             
                    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                        print(result)
                    }
                }else {
                    print("No Data")
                }
                
            } catch let JsonError {
                print("fetch json error:", JsonError.localizedDescription)
            }
            
        }.resume()
    }
```

The create post is wrapped in a class ViewDataBase with other CRUD commands...

I have a struct postDataBase where i know the error The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format. could be happening as well. I've changed these to various data types with no success

```
struct postDataBase: Decodable {
    var ID: String
    var title: String
    var post: String
}
```

My php code is here. I use bluehost to support my database so i can have a public domain. If you need my username and password let me know i can change it later.

```
<?php

$connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","****","****");

$ID = $_POST['ID'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$post = $_POST['post'];
 

    if(!$connection)
    {
        die('Connection Failed');
    }
    else
    {
        $dbconnect = @mysqli_select_db('mlbroadv_PlantAssistDB', $connection);

        if(!$dbconnect)
        {
            die('Could not connect to Database');
        }
        else
        {
            $query = "INSERT INTO Notes (title, post) VALUES ( '$title', '$post');";
            mysqli_query($query, $connection) or die(mysqli_error());

            echo 'Successfully added.';
            echo $query;
        }
    }
?>
```

My goal is getting my swift data uploaded to php and into mySQL database. There seems to be a disconnect somewhere...

I think the error lies in the following code where the php files is read in to connect with mySQL and to upload my variables...

EDIT:

```
  let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = data
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        
    
      URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request ) { (data, res, error) in
```

EDIT 2: Still Trying to get it

For this line...

```
let parameters: [String: Any] = ["title": "Fgh", "post": "Fgg"
```

I get...

```
Param raw data is coded as:  ["post": "Fgg", "title": "Fgh"]
```

For this line...

```
    let dataParam = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters)
```

I Get...

```
json serialization request is coded as:  28 bytes
```

For this line...

```
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest ) { (data, res, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("urlsession error is coded as: ", error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
            return
        }
```

I Get for the data varaible...

```
urlsession data is coded as:  235 bytes
```

and for the res variable, I get the following repsonse...

```
urlsession results is coded as:  <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x282ea64c0> { URL: https://mlbroadvisions.com/post.php } { Status Code: 200, Headers {
    "Content-Encoding" =     (
        gzip
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Fri, 22 Jul 2022 16:07:03 GMT"
    );
    Server =     (
        cloudflare
    );
    Vary =     (
        "Accept-Encoding"
    );
    "cf-cache-status" =     (
        DYNAMIC
    );
    "cf-ray" =     (
        "72ed6d53f9072be1-ORD"
    );
    "expect-ct" =     (
        "max-age=604800, report-uri=\"https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct\""
    );
    "host-header" =     (
        "c2hhcmVkLmJsdWVob3N0LmNvbQ=="
    );
} }
```

during the ...

```
catch let error as NSError {
                   print(error.localizedDescription)
```

It gives me the error...

```
The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
json data is coded as:  235 bytes
```

What part of my code do i need to change to get it into the correct format i've tried a lot of things none of which worked.

Comment: Your swift code sends JSON data to a program called post.php on your server. I don't know PHP very well, but I don't see any code to handle data being sent by a POST from a remote server. You only show mysql code. Where is the code that tries to read the JSON data?

Comment: I added an edit where i think the php file is uploaded and the parameters are read into the php file to connect to mySQL

Comment: I'd start with `let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters)` - my guess is that whatever type `post` is, is not serializable. Better error handling there would tell you if my guess is correct.

Comment: You are sending plain JSON as a request body. PHP doesn't know what to do with that and will not auto-decode this data into a $_POST array. Try sending regular POST request with form-URL-encoded data just as browsers do. Or, on PHP side - read your data from `php://input` and `json_decode` it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)

Comment: I'm still trying to get it. In the EDIT 2 I reported as many variables as i could and gettign the same error